# Angular array Boolean into an array of strings

Tags: angularjs

Hey I am trying to display only the "text" that is checked: "true" from an array of boolean values.. Selected data is rendered in a "surveylist" view, then upon clicking the survey item you are directed to a "surveymore" view which shows the lot of data. it is in the "surveymore" that i'd like to filter..basically only rendering "Allergies" and not { text: "Allergies", checked: true} for example.

Surveylist view:

```
<ion-item  ng-class="" ng-repeat="object in lines"  class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-text-wrap" href="#/moresurvey/{{object.id}}">

<a><h2>{{object.visafname}}</h2></a>
<h2 >{{object.visalname}}</h2>
<p>{{object.gender}}</p>
   <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

      </ion-item>
```

Surveymore view:

```
<ion-item class="item more-item">
     <p class="moredetails location"> Ailments: </br> </br>

   {{Details.diagnosed}}</p>

  </ion-item>
```

Scope:

```
$scope.Diagnosed = [
        { text: "Allergies", checked: true},
        { text: "ADHD", checked: false},
        { text: "Alcohol/Drug Dependence", checked: false},
        { text: "Asthma", checked: false},
        { text: "Autism", checked: false},
        { text: "Cancer", checked: false},
        { text: "Diabetes", checked: false},
        { text: "Eating Disorder", checked: false},
        { text: "Fertility Problems", checked: false},
        { text: "Heart Disease", checked: false},
        { text: "High Cholesterol", checked: false},
        { text: "Menopause", checked: false},
        { text: "Mood Disorders (e.g., anxiety, depression)", checked: false},
        { text: "Obesity", checked: false},
        { text: "Stroke", checked: false},
        { text: "Prefer not to answer", checked: false}

        ];
```

return scope looks like this:

```
$scope.Details.diagnosed = _.filter( $scope.Details.diagnosed, function(object){ 
return object.checked == true;
})
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the objects that have the value `checked === true`, you could do something like this:

```
var arrayOfObjs = $scope.Diagnosed.filter(function (value) {
  return value.checked;
});
```

Also if you want to get only the texts, you could do it:

```
var arrayOfTexts = $scope.Diagnosed.filter(function(value) {
  return value.checked;
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.text;
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to display it in view, you can simply use the *native* `filter`:

```
<p ng-repeat="d in Diagnosed | filter: { checked: true }" ng-bind="d.text"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How would I implement this when ng-repeat is being used in the view before we get to the view that shows the array? like this ---> <ion-item ng-class="" ng-repeat="object in lines" class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-text-wrap" href="#/moresurvey/{{object.id}}">...but uppon clicking the item it goes to the view with more information, which will show the diagnosed array.

Comment: Can you please edit your question posting what you're trying to do in your view? It would be great.

Comment: Yes, I changed it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

you could use ng-if.

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed
>   and a new scope is created when the element is restored.

```js
  angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.Diagnosed = [
        { text: "Allergies", checked: true},
        { text: "ADHD", checked: false},
        { text: "Alcohol/Drug Dependence", checked: false},
        { text: "Asthma", checked: false},
        { text: "Autism", checked: false},
        { text: "Cancer", checked: false},
        { text: "Diabetes", checked: false},
        { text: "Eating Disorder", checked: false},
        { text: "Fertility Problems", checked: false},
        { text: "Heart Disease", checked: false},
        { text: "High Cholesterol", checked: false},
        { text: "Menopause", checked: false},
        { text: "Mood Disorders (e.g., anxiety, depression)", checked: false},
        { text: "Obesity", checked: false},
        { text: "Stroke", checked: false},
        { text: "Prefer not to answer", checked: false}

        ];
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in Diagnosed" ng-if="d.checked">{{d.text}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I implement this when ng-repeat is being used in the view before we get to the view that shows the array? like this  ---> <ion-item  ng-class="" ng-repeat="object in lines"  class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-text-wrap" href="#/moresurvey/{{object.id}}">...but uppon clicking the item it goes to the view with more information, which will show the diagnosed array.

Comment: yes when ng-repeat is being used as shown in example. as ng-repeat will do it's job then your data before showing in the view pass throw ng-if and ng-if do it's magic :-)
<ion-item ng-class="" ng-repeat="object in lines" ng-if="object.checked" class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-text-wrap" href="#/moresurvey/{{object.id}}">

Comment: what information? you mean checked property from object? it's removing only objects not the property of object.

Comment: Well there is a survey object that has a diagnosed object which has the array...so it only shows <a><h2>{{object.name}}</h2></a> initially, but once click it shows the rest of the data that was collected in the survey like this --> <ion-item class="item more-item"> <p class="moredetails location">Ailments(other):</br> </br>
    {{Details.diagnosed}}</p>
  </ion-item>